# how to unit test sprocs in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, t-sql

I have some sprocs in ss2012 and I want to unit test them.  I haven't unit tested sprocs before.  Based on a quick Google, it seems that I should be able to right-click a sproc and select "Create Unit Tests" from the context menu. However, this option is not available in my SSMS instance.  Are sproc unit tests not natively supported in SSMS 2012 or is there some type of additional software that I need to download and install?

Answer (score 2):

This is available within SSDT database projects.

I'm not sure what the exact requirements are for version of Visual Studio but certainly I see the "Create Unit Tests" option when right clicking stored procedures in database projects opened in VS2015 Community Edition.

It creates a test project where you can configure tests [as outlined here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833423(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use tSQLt framework (behind the scenes it's just some tables and stored procedures created in your database), that's the only SQL Server unit testing framework I know.

What you've seen in Google is probably [SQL Test](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-test/) done by Red Gate.

In fact, you don't have to use it, it's just a GUI that lets you execute SQLCop unit tests, done in tSQLt framework, in a easier manner.

You can execute them without problem by calling the actual tSQLt procedures.

Answer (score 0):

tSQLt is the best framework to use. It is powerful, well supported and open source. There is [a good tutorial](http://tsqlt.org/user-guide/quick-start/) on the official website that will get you started.

If you happen to have a license the Redgate SQL Toolbelt, you'll have access to [SQL Test](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-test/), providing deeper SSMS integration. This is essentially a tSQLt runner that makes it easier to install the framework and run the tests, but isn't a requirement to use tSQLt.

If you don't have SQL Test but need to download the SQL Cop tests, you can do so using the link at the bottom of [this documentation page](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SQT1/SQL+Cop+static+analysis+tests). SQL Cop tests aren't strictly unit tests. They are more about checking for best practices.